# Identifikation of components GTE PSA 18B

Tags: power-electronics, identification

[image: strange part]

Trying to idenify a device inside a kid's toy car. It is a two pin part with ca. 19 * 10 * 30 mm dimensions. It is located within one wire of three leading to the two motors of the car. UnfortuSeems to be a power device as it has two thick (3mm) copper rods as connectors. Wires are welded to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a common PTC thermistor reversible fuse. I couldn't find data about it, just see the motor parameters and find a replacement.

Google is your friend, search "ptc thermistor fuse calculator"

Comment: I think your idea is the most reasonable explanation. However in this case I don't need a replacement. I really wanted to know what it is to understand the circuit.

Comment: @Ariser It has only two pins to be something else, it's to big for a normal fuse, it is so big to protect other car components from the heat on overload

Comment: Considering this, I'm sure the part is ok, because it lets current pass :)

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm. This is a thermal fuse. Bought a few of these on surplus for cheap. Power wheels part no seems to be 80370 as mine are power wheels branded and in original (NOS) blister packs, dated 1993.

Still looking for the parameters (cut off temp - etc)